# Initializing Char array member in C++ class constructor

Tags: c++, c

I have to use a c style struct inside a c++ class ( I can do with string but I have to use specifically a C-style struct with char array) as

```
typedef struct
{
 char arr[6];
} STYPE1;
class A
{
 public:
  void SetArr( const char* str ) { 
       strncpy(m_sTYPE1.arr , str , 5);
       m_sTYPE1.arr[5]='\0';
  }
private:
  STYPE1 m_sTYPE1;
} ;
```

1. How to initialize the member `m_sTYPE1` in initialization list
2. Without having anything in ctor, calling `SetArr` with `"ABCDE"` throws an error as `strncpy` crashes. I assume this is because `m_sTYPE1.arr` is not initialized properly. How to initialize  and later set the string?

The whole thing becomes lot easier with C++ string, but here I am interested only in C-Style char array implementation.

Comment: Why can't you use a `std::string`?

Comment: Can you add the code snippet which crashes ?

Comment: One of the hard things is that `arr[6]='\0'` is out of bounds. The index range is 0 to 5.

Comment: And why `typedef struct {} STYPE1` instead of proper `struct STYPE1 {}`? Or at least be concise and do `typedef class {} A` too.

Comment: I need to use C-style char array as I am using this code in quering data from embedded  C sql

Comment: you know about `string::c_str()`?

Comment: Bo Persson thank you for pointing out. I edited the above post. I still get a crash at strncpy. How to initialize char arr in class ctor

Comment: Revolver_Ocelot typedef struct {} STYPE1 is c-style struct,

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as a c-style struct in C++.  If you are compiling with a C++ compiler then a `struct` is the same as a `class` accept for the default access level.  Just because you use the archaic C syntax does not make it a C struct.

Comment: NathanOliver  agree, STYPE1 is simply an alias here. The main issue however is the crash while callig strncpy and I want to understand why it crashes.

Comment: @Sree show us a [mcve]. There are no calls to `SetArr` in your example. There can be no calls outside the class either because you defined it private.

Comment: @Sree well done fixing the access specifier. But the program still doesn't compile (there is a missing semicolon) and there are still no calls to `SetArr`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to initialize the member m_sTYPE1 in initiliatization list

Using list initialization (which in this case does aggregate initialization):

```
A::A(): m_sTYPE1{} {}
```

> 2. Without having anything in ctor, calling SetArr with "ABCDE" throws error as strncpy crashes. I assume this is because m_sTYPE1.arr is not initialized properly.

Initializing `m_sTYPE1` in the constructor has no effect on whether `SetArr` "*throws an error*". Copying over uninitialized memory is completely safe. If `strncpy` "*crashes*", then there is a bug elsewhere. It's impossible to say where, because your example is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not Java, You have declared the private member `S_TYPE1 m_sTYPE1` and it will simply exist in every instance of class `A`, it is not a pointer or reference and therefore does not need to point to or reference an existing object.

If by *initialization list* you mean you want to set the byte range when constructing `A` - I would suggest declaring a constructor that accepts a `const char* const` and then copy the data from it. Define a constructor that takes a `char*&&` if you want to move.

However, Looking at your example, I'll also mention that arrays are zero-based in C/C++ and thus declaring `arr[6]` gives you valid indices between `0-5`, 6 is out of bounds and attempting to access it or write to it will result in undefined behaviour (read: probably crash your program) so your line of code manually setting the null-terminator will not work.